# How to design a metal plate for PCB

Tags: pcb, rf, pcb-design, wifi, shielding

I am designing a Esp8266-based WiFi module and I'm not sure if I need one of those metal plates. They are suppose to protect a sensitive area from EMI/RFI, right? Also, how can I design one with custom measures and writing?

Here is an example:

This is with the shield on

[image: PCB with shield]

This is with the shield removed

[image: PCB with shield removed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These shields are used to deaden EMI/RFI both *to* the circuit, and *from* the circuit.

I have seen them most often used to contain RF noise so that the product passes regulatory emissions testing.

Also, these can help "modularize" the design.  One of the problems with RF circuitry is that the tuning changes with the surroundings.  Generally an RF-enabled product is tested while it's in the case/package that it will be used in.  If you change (or remove) the case, the RF path can go out of tune.  Isolating your RF circuitry inside one of these faraday cages can minimize the external influences on the product.

The shields come in a large assortment of dimensions.  [Here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-shields/3539677) is a link to DigiKey's RF shielding products.  As far as customizing the case with your logo or part number: this is often done with a laser etcher, but a simple label is easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Google board level shielding. It's essentially a faraday cage. I've used some from LeaderTech to protect my GPS RF front end. There are many versions to choose from depending on if you use SMT or need AOI.

[Here's](http://www.leadertechinc.com/assets/files/EngineeringDrawings/ONE%20PIECE%20SHIELD.PDF) a one piece shield technical drawing.